# Getting iTMS attached country on iphone

Tags: iphone

I am getting a link to iTMS using this url :

http://ax.phobos.apple.com.edgesuite.net/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/wa/itmsSearch?WOURLEncoding=ISO8859_1&lang=1&output=json&country=ES&term=OASIS

The problem I have is when I get the link to buy the song, and my iTunes store is Canada, the link is not working, since countries are different.

I need to change country value regarding country set in user's iphone. Do you know how to do this ?

Thanks a lot

Thierry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it !
Get the user country.

Comment: Can you explain how you did that?